# What allows bash to autocomplete tmux "sub-commands"?

Tags: bash, tmux, autocomplete

I'm trying to replicate some useful features from my work PC at home.

At work, `bash` will helpfully autocomplete `tmux` "sub-commands": e.g. I type "`tmux new-s<tab>`" and bash autocompletes that to "`tmux new-session`" (I hope "sub-command" is the right term). **This doesn't happen on my home PC -- what can I do to set this up on my home PC?**

I've looked around online and found some references to auto-complete *within `tmux`*, e.g. to auto-complete commands like `move-window` -- but that's not what I'm looking for.
I also found reference to a feature called "bash complete" -- but on my work PC, I don't find any reference to `tmux` in my `~/.bash_completion` file or my `/etc/bash_completion.d/` directory.

**Can someone please explain either where/how else my work PC might have set up its `tmux` "sub-command" autocompletion (so that I can refer/learn from a working example), or how I can/should set this up?**

Interesting side-note: both my work and home PCs autocomplete `git` "sub-commands"; e.g. typing "`git clo<tab>`" autocompletes to "`git clone`". I didn't do anything specific to set that up -- for both `git` and `tmux`, all I did as far as setup was "`sudo apt install git`" and "`sudo apt install tmux`", respectively.

Comment: Check output of `complete -p tmux`.

Comment: @Cyrus - on both work and home PCs, `complete -p tmux` outputs "`-bash: complete: tmux: no completion specification`"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get your systems completion dir from `pkg-config --variable=completionsdir bash-completion` (/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/)

This is where dynamic completions are set up:

```
$ complete -p git
-bash: complete: git: no completion specification
$ git st<TAB>
st       stage    stash    status   sti
$ complete -p git
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap__git_main git
```

If you want to set up tmux auto complete follow https://russellparker.me/post/2018/02/16/tmux-bash-autocomplete/

Answer (score 8):

laktak's answer worked on my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop. I simply ran:

```bash
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/imomaliev/tmux-bash-completion/master/completions/tmux > ~/.bash_completion
```

Comment: works for me "Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"

Comment: Works for me in Ubuntu 22.04 as well! I just copied the file in more dedicated folder like `/etc/bash_completion.d/`: `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/imomaliev/tmux-bash-completion/master/completions/tmux | sudo tee /etc/bash_completion.d/tmux > /dev/null`

Comment: Beware that this overwrites anything you might have previously had in `~/.bash_completion` Also, this only takes effect after doing something like `. /etc/bash_completion`, which is common in a `~/.bashrc`.